# Exchange: Find items in EWS conversation using XML request?

Tags: xml, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to find the items in a conversation using Exchange EWS 2010, *regardless* of the folder they're in. And I don't want to get a list of all the conversationId's in a single folder. I'd like to query on a conversation by conversation basis.

I'm doing this on Android, and have been sending XML soap requests fine for other EWS requests.

My problem is this:

**How should the XML be formatted to retrieve the items in a single conversation, given it's ConversationId?**

I've tried using FindItem with Restriction and with a QueryString, but neither seem to give any results.

Is there a way to do so? I'm familiar with the "FindConversations" operation, but it seems to return all messages for all conversations in folder. I want the messages for a specific conversation.

Here are 2 example XML requests I've tried.

**Attempt using QueryString:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeReceived" />
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:From" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="10" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
      <m:QueryString>item:ConversationId:AAQkADg5MmFjNTViLTYwODUtNGNmYi04MzhjLTczZTdkOTZmYjllNwAQAA/J3OiwUmlBntyd9PhAWBM=</m:QueryString>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Attempt using Restriction:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
     xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
     xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="50" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
      <m:Restriction>
          <t:IsEqualTo>
            <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ConversationId" />
            <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
              <t:Constant Value="AAQkADg5MmFjNTViLTYwODUtNGNmYi04MzhjLTczZTdkOTZmYjllNwAQAA/J3OiwUmlBntyd9PhAWBM="/>
            </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
          </t:IsEqualTo>
      </m:Restriction>
      <m:SortOrder>
        <t:FieldOrder Order="Descending">
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:DateTimeReceived" />
        </t:FieldOrder>
      </m:SortOrder>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to search for messages based on ConversationIndex. I'm using "JWebServices for Exchange" API on Java/Android. You have to use findItem method with restriction and use PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX field (standard MAPI property). Code is like:

```
        IsEqualTo restriction = new IsEqualTo(MapiPropertyTag.PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX, "AA3OiwUmlB...");

        FindItemResponse response = service.findItem(StandardFolder.INBOX, restriction);
```

Comment: hey... thanks for the feedback... i was really hoping to see what the raw XML looked like for such a request.... Is there a way for you to dump this when you do that request? I'd love to see it ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to nearly work, but it only returns items from one folder.... not all folders ;-(

Note that PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX = 0x0071

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"/>
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="5" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning"/>
      <m:Restriction>
        <t:Or>
          <t:IsEqualTo>
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x0071" PropertyType="Binary"/>
            <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
              <t:Constant Value="Ac7BH8JjB509L0wAfEakbAl7ATtZhA=="/>
            </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
          </t:IsEqualTo>
          <t:IsEqualTo>
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x0071" PropertyType="Binary"/>
            <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
              <t:Constant Value="AQHOgWGUK7JmFnIm5E6tWXtmj4J2FplmRcIA"/>
            </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
          </t:IsEqualTo>
          <t:IsEqualTo>
            <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x0071" PropertyType="Binary"/>
            <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
              <t:Constant Value="AQHOcazuyUKjqFgn8Eq0mqIHnczJhplGdo5DgABT/gA="/>
            </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
          </t:IsEqualTo>
        </t:Or>
      </m:Restriction>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```